# Yii2 compare validator with null value

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using a `dateTimeComparealidator` and i have 4 fields to compare.

1 .`earlyOpenDate` (should be less than `startDate` if its not `null`)

2 .`earlyCloseDate` (should be greater than `earlyOpenDate` if its not `null`)

3 .`startDate` (should be greater than `earlyOpenDate` if `earlyOpenDate` is not null)

4 .`endDate` (should be greater than `endDate`)

In this `startDate` and `endDate` are mandatory but other 2 are optional.

So my validator doesnt work when i have `null` value in `earlyOpenDate`.

When i select any value in `startDate` it throws error that `startDate` should be greater than `earlyOpenDate`.

Is there any way without modifying the validator class to achieve this.

And also when i select the `endDate` without selecting `startDate` it displays error message but when i select the `startDate` after selecting `endDate` the message it still there until i reselect the date.

It doesnt automatically invoke the validation.

i am using [this extension](https://github.com/empathy/yii2-datetime-compare) for datetime validation

I also tried to use 'when' validator with condition in `yii2` but its not working as expected.

Comment: Can you show us your validation rules please?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-enforcing `skipOnEmpty` (should be the default but the extension could redefine the default) and / or if related `skipOnError`:

```
[..., 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'skipOnError' => ...],
```